# Post from app does not appear in user's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-timeline

Since Facebook made Timeline now public, the my app post using stream publish does not appear in user's Timeline, only in News Feed. Is there's anything we should do about this or anything new on publish stream or feed post regarding the new Timeline feature ?

Comment: What Facebook SDK are you using? JS, PHP, iOS etc.

Comment: Isn't it not really public yet (to give people chance to hide their shady past)?

Comment: yea, I think @SergeiTulentsev is right, with the new timeline in place , you are able to programmatically post to the users feed (home feed), but that won't necessarily show up on the timeline because the timeline shows things(actions/events) that the *user* did, not what *applications* did on the users behalf.

Comment: PHP and JS SDK , i'm using FB.UI stream publish method to post the app post to wall. Yes, timeline is not public yet, but some facebook users now switching to timeline. It only appear when I feature (when i see my timeline activity log) the post at timeline, on the other hand, not

Comment: ^ I think you right. Thanks you @Sean and Sergei for the thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Your application should have read_stream publish_stream and permissions (I think this is enough).
You should send POST request to this URL https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed

You can read more about it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

The user has to share the content manually using the Share Dialog. Everything that gets shared automatically by your app gets to the newsfeed instead of the wall. Here's an example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

**Update as of December 2016,**

I myself tested the whole process. I made a PHP script using facebook PHP SDK. what my script does is to post on my facebook page every single hour on my behalf.
The astonishing thing that i found was that the content posted through the script has got very less organic promotion compared to the content posted manually.

**Mathematical Analysis:**

**Posting Through Script:**

A post on my page + The same post is shared on 54 groups. Nos of views: **4**

**Native Posting:**

A post on my page + The same post is shared on 37 groups. Nos of views: **34996**

Answer (score -1):

Before an **action** going to public you need to submit an action and it must be approved by Facebook , then only every action comes public visibility